# Why I can't scan the WhatsApp QR?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Why I can't scan the Whatsapp QR?

- I reinstalled WhatsApp
- I already have the WhatsApp Web Option
- I put it to scan but it just doesn't scan it.
- I Installed a QR Scanner app and it works perfectly.
- I uninstalled the QR Scanner app to see if that was the issue and
  still doesn't work.

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Ace.

Comment: Is the problem that the page won't open, or that the app won't scan the QR at all? Have you tried a different scanning app? (I recommend [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android).)

Comment: Are you holding the device correctly enough for the QR scanner to work ! I somewhere doubt that this is still a new service which might be the reason why things are going a little out of the....

Comment: I am having Sony live with walkman, and also I can't able to scan the code, beside that NeoReader is able to scan the code easily. On scanning the code, it shows some of the garbage text(might a be a session cookie or signature to verify the account).
If anyone is facing the same problem and have any workaround for that, Please post here. . . ..

Comment: Well, you don't need to look for the third part QR code scanners rather than the QR scanner can be found on the whatsapp itself. I think people are getting problem because they are installing third party QR code scanners. Open the Whatsapp>Menu>Whats app Web

Comment: ***** My problem was in an adware called "Superfish" that came with my brand new *Lenovo* Y50. I removed it and got the QR right away.

Comment: I managed to scan the native app in Windows, installed from the link https://www.whatsapp.com/download/

Comment: My 2 cents: *****if you're running any extension that changes the page's colors*****, it can be the culprit because it might change the default colors of the QR code (black on white). In my case I was running the Dark Reader extension. So, I disabled it, ran the QR code scan, and enabled it again. I got this solution from [this answer](https://forums.androidcentral.com/showthread.php?t=851791&s=b59d6b59d28c067a552685db88b67030&p=6089154&viewfull=1#post6089154)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SOLUTION

Okay, first of all - you have to scan the QR-Code with the scanner that is built in WhatsApp. Not with some 3rd-party scanner-app. Click on "Whatsapp Web", then the scanner opens immediately.

BUT - apparently there is a problem with devices that have a display smaller than 4 inches!

Like with my Sony Xperia Go (3,5 inches), I can't tap on the "OK, got it"-button to make the instructions of the built-in-scanner go away.

That's it. They will have to solve this problem in a later version, I guess.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That's it! I can't see the "Ok, got it" on my screen. Thank you all!

Comment: If you are root user and you install xposed framework, then you'll be able to install a module for executing apps in smaller size. I did that on a friend's phone and I could see the ok, got it message

Comment: It seems there is a new update that fixed this issue based on [this answer on other post](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/96689/44325): version 2.11.505

Comment: new update released by Whatsapp !! now its working :)

Answer (score 5):

Turn off WiFi.

Apparently, WhatsApp only connects itself to the web session if it's online via mobile data.

Comment: That was it. I've now tried turning off and on WiFi several times - it immediately works when on LTE, it never works on WiFi. Funny thing is that WhatsApp itself suggests "Connect through wifi to reduce your data traffic". So I disabled WiFi, scanned the code, re-enabled the WiFi and now it works. The only explanation I can find is that it is using some service to map my LTE IP back to my phone number. I'll try later from *another* phone, connected with WiFi first to my home ADSL, then to my phone's LTE network. If it works, and with the former only, that will clinch it. Meanwhile, +1.

Comment: You would think that the WhatsApp app should tell you this when trying to scan a QR code.

Comment: Didn't work to me.

Answer (score 4):

To repeat a comment by Almir Campos that solved my issue: If your browser has an extension such as Dark Reader which makes pages night-themed and inverts the color of the QR code, WhatsApp won't be able to scan it. Make sure you disable any color-inverting extensions or settings on web.whatsapp.com before scanning the QR code.

Comment: Yes, this is a very common problem that people don't really think at first