# Why I can't scan QR code inside Whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have Whatsapp latest version & have the Whatsapp Web Option
I put it to scan but it just doesn't scan it.
I Installed a QR Scanner app and it works perfectly.
I uninstalled the QR Scanner app to see if that was the issue and still doesn't work.
My phone is a Sony Xperia E1 Dual... anyone help me...

Comment: Probably related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96546/why-i-cant-scan-the-whatsapp-qr

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install third party QR scanner, rather than you have to use the QR scanner present inside the whatsapp it can be found under whatsapp>Menu>WebWhatsApp, use it to scan the QR Code and your problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the WhatsApp Web option, does a visual guide pop up? There should be an ”OK, got it” button to clear it, but apparently on devices with smaller displays there’s a bug which caused the button to not appear. If that’s the case, wait for an update (version 2.11.505). I just got mine, and it works now.