# Why I cant scan the the Whatsapp QR code?

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, android-sdk, qr-code

I have tryed to scan the QR code using whatsapp for web, also I see the: ok, I got it, then a green line start to scan but noting happened, I just downloaded the app yesterday night and also Im in the right position of the phone and monitor.

Please can you help me? I have a: Samsung Galaxy Pro B7510.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96546/why-i-cant-scan-the-whatsapp-qr

Answer (score 0):

Personally I noticed that if I move the device further back from the screen it seems to help.Try moving it a bit from the screen.