# QR Scan in WhatsApp doesn't work (QR loads but phone scan never ends)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, qr-code

**Not the same as** [Why I can't scan the WhatsApp QR?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96546/why-i-cant-scan-the-whatsapp-qr) **because the problem there was the "OK Got It" was not visible due to the screen being too small, but that's not the problem here**

I have the latest version of WhatsApp

I restarted the phone

I have the WhatsApp Web option

The QR code loads perfectly in my chrome browser

**I have the "OK Got It" option**

It starts scanning the code....
.....and keeps scanning and scanning and scanning.....

I waited over 15 minutes and nothing happened! **It just keeps scanning the code**, no matter how many times I reload it, and nothing happens :(

I tested my internet and wifi connections, so I know it's not that.

Anyone else have this problem? Or know how to fix this?

I have a galaxy s3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I can't scan the WhatsApp QR?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96546/why-i-cant-scan-the-whatsapp-qr)

Comment: Nope. That problem was that they couldn't see the "OK Got It" button.  Does not apply here, as I do see that, and I can scan the code... it just never stops scanning :(

Comment: lower the brightness of your PC screen, it may help.

Comment: just tried that now and it still just keeps scanning away.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Bizarrely, after trying Windows app, various browsers & so on, I ran a copy of Chrome Canary I have set up to explicitly not use normal user profile and it works. Unlikely this information is any use to anyone else...

Answer (score 1):

I found that a Chrome extension I had was causing the built in scanner to fail. DarkReader modified the background of the page to a dark colour, which apparently caused the WhatsApp QR scanner to fail.

If you are using dark mode plugin, ensure it's off when scanning the QR code.

Answer (score 0):

Mine wouldn't scan when phone was on wifi; turned off wifi and it worked perfectly.